# How to monitor user inactivity without using d-bus on ubuntu 22.04 using gnome 42.9

Tags: gnome, keyboard, mouse, video, python3

**How to monitor user inactivity from kb or mouse without using d-bus and tracking any video fullscreen or small screen on ubuntu 22.04 using gnome 42.9**

I already have a solution using dbus however since the latest update it has become unreliable.

I am looking for a python script that will take the time from system 'screen blank' var as the input time for this script. Also looking at if user is playing any video full screen or small screen and looking at any user activity from the kb or mouse move then print "User has gone idle" if no video is playing and then if mouse or kb activity then print "User has come back from idle"

The problem is I don't have a PC monitor connected to my PC
I have a TV with CEC capabilities so can turn TV on and off from a script however when the dpms off signal occurs my TV just says no video signal so I made this script years ago used in conjunction with caffeine it has worked fine for years until now so I'm looking for a better solution

```
#!/bin/bash

toggle=0

# Function to handle screen off and set toggle
handle_screen_off() {
  if [[ "$toggle" == "0" ]]; then
    echo "Screen is off!"
    toggle=1
    echo off > /home/user/bin/command.txt
  fi
}

# Function to handle screen on and reset toggle
handle_screen_on() {
  if [[ "$toggle" == "1" ]]; then
    echo "Screen is on!"
    toggle=0
    echo on > /home/user/bin/command.txt
  fi    
}

# Monitor screen saver state
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
while read x; do
  case "$x" in
    *"boolean true"*) handle_screen_off;;
    *"boolean false"*) handle_screen_on;;
  esac
done

#dbus-monitor is cmd to see what signal is used
```

I also found this code however it does not handle video tracking and its not python.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define a function to handle the keyboard interrupt signal
function handle_interrupt {
  echo "Loop interrupted. Exiting..."
  exit 0
}

# Trap the keyboard interrupt signal and associate it with the handle_interrupt function
trap handle_interrupt SIGINT

# Function to handle setting idle time
function set_idletime() {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    # Use default idle time if no argument provided
    echo "No idle time provided. Using default of $idletime seconds."
  else
    new_idle_time="$1"
    if [[ ! "$new_idle_time" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
      echo "Error: Idle time must be a positive integer."
      exit 1
    fi
    echo "Setting idle time to $new_idle_time seconds."
    idletime="$new_idle_time"
  fi
}

# Set default idle time first
idletime=10 # seconds

# Then call set_idletime to handle potential arguments
set_idletime "$1"

# Optional echo to confirm the idle time being used
echo "Using idle time of $idletime seconds."

idleloop() {
    touch /tmp/.{,last_}input
    cmd='stat --printf="%s"'
    #idletime=10 # seconds 
    echo "Using idle time of $idletime seconds."

    a=2
    t=0
    while true
    do
        timeout 1 xinput test-xi2 --root > /tmp/.input
        
        if [[ `eval $cmd /tmp/.input` == `eval $cmd /tmp/.last_input` ]]
        then
            let t++ # increases $t by 1
        else
            t=0     # resets $t
        fi

        mv /tmp/.{,last_}input -f

        if [ $t -ge $idletime ] && [[ $a == "2" ]]
        then
            echo "user has gone idle"
            a=1
        fi
        if [ $t -lt $idletime ] && [[ $a == "1" ]]
        then
            echo "user has come back from idle"
            a=2
        fi
    done
}

idleloop
```

So ideally I would like to use as little as possible as regards external libraries.

Thanks in advance for any help.